# Share page on Facebook without open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-share

This is my first question so I apologize in advance for any format errors or anything else.

I have to share the page (title, description, photo, link) without using an open graph. This is because the contents are read by `DB` in `Java` and inserted into the page with `js/jquery` and, according to what I read, `Facebook` does not consider `js` but only the source code.

Is it possible to pass parameters dynamically with `js/jquery`?
I know that you can directly share the link as [shown here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog): But I read in the documentation that it is no longer possible to pass title, description, and photo as parameters.

I must be absolutely sure that the title, description, and photos are displayed in the post.

Comment: The only way left to set those values dynamically, is when you are posting to a _page_ of yours via API, and you have claimed “ownership” of the domain that the content you are sharing is from first.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/page/feed#custom-image

Comment: I seem to understand, from what he wrote and from the link, which this allows to publish on my company page, not to share normally.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what that means.